# Zend MultiCheckbox input attribute

Tags: php, html, zend-framework

I have a multicheckbox element like that:

```
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox('infos', array('disableLoadDefaultDecorators' => true));
$element->addDecorator('ViewHelper')
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->addMultiOption('value1', 'BLABLABLA')
        ->addMultiOption('value2', 'BLABLABLA2')
        ->addValidator('NotEmpty', true);
$element->getValidator('NotEmpty')->setMessage('Pelo menos uma informação é necessária');
$this->addElement($element);
```

When i render a multicheckbox element, it appears like that:

```
<p>     
     <label for="infos-value1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="infos[]" id="infos-value1" value="value1">BLABLABLA
     </label><br>
     <label for="infos-value2">
             <input type="checkbox" name="infos[]" id="infos-value2" value="value2">BLABLABLA2
     </label><br>
 </p>
```

And i want to add an attribute for only, let's say, the first input, so the first input would be something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="infos[]" id="infos-value1" value="value1" disabled>BLABLABLA
 </label><br>
```

How do i add the attribute "disabled" to just one of my two inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply pass the indexes for the options to disable like so:

`$element->setOptions(array('disable' => array('value1', 'value2')));`

Not sure this is very well documented anyplace.  I am hoping to see some improvements with multi-selects in ZF 2.0.  Currently they do have their limitations.  Specifically setting class or style attributes on individual options.  I have had to extend/add alternate element classes and view helpers to get around some of those issues in the past.  Easy enough to do if you must.